# Sum of the zeroes of $x^4-7x^3+2x^2+5x-1=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Someone posed this question to me on a forum, and I have yet to figure it out. If $a,b,c,d$ are the zeroes of:

$$x^4-7x^3+2x^2+5x-1=0$$
Then what is the value of $$ \frac1a +\frac1b +\frac1c +\frac1d $$

I can figure out the zeroes, but they are wildly complex. I'm sure there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 7):

$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) = x^4 + \ldots - (abc+abd+acd+bcd)x + abcd$$
So $$abcd = -1$$ and 
$$abc + abd + acd + bcd = abcd \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac1c + \frac1d\right) = -5$$
making
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac1c + \frac1d = 5$$

Answer (score 3):

If $P(x)=x^4-7x^3+2x^2+5x-1$ has roots $a,b,c,d$ then $\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{c}, \frac{1}{d}$ are the roots of $P(\frac{1}{x})=0$ $\iff$ $1-7x+2x^2+5x^3-x^4=0$. By Vieta's relations, the sum of the roots of the latter is $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f(x)$ has roots $a,b,c,d$ then $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$. Expand this out and compare coefficients with the given quartic. (In particular, the coefficients of $x^3$ and $x^0$.)